# Google closure optimization errors with google maps library

Tags: google-maps, clojure, clojurescript, google-closure-compiler

I'm trying to include this library: https://clojars.org/gmapscljs for my clojurescript front-end. I'm having some trouble making it work with google closure optimization. When I add the gmapscljs dependency to my project.clj i can no longer use any optimization i get this error:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Externs zip must match our hard-coded list of externs.`

If I use no optimization I still get a lot of warnings:

`WARNING: No such namespace: goog.object, could not locate goog/object.cljs, goog/object.cljc, or Closure namespace "" at line 23 target/cljsbuild/public/js/out/devtools/format.cljs
...`

The gmapscljs library seems to work fine with the warnings.

This is the only example i can find in the wild using the same library, it's a sample project by the creator of the library.

https://github.com/fyquah95/gmapscljs-example

how to reproduce:

`lein new reagent my-app`

and add

`[gmaps-cljs "0.0.2"]` to project clj

`lein cljsbuild once` will generate warnings
`lein uberjar` will generate errors

Comment: did you `(:require [goog.object])` ?

Comment: no, but I tried to add [goog.object] in the cljs core file now, but it didn't make a difference.